# Problem with this react flow, maximum update depth exceeded

Tags: reactjs

I have the following function

```
 compareProducts = (empresa) => {
    console.log(empresa.listaProductos)
    let headerSetIn = false;
    for (let i in empresa.listaProductos) {
      //case1 : lookup for some data in an array, if found, setState and exit the whole function
      if (pFichaInternacional && pFichaInternacional.length > 0) {
        console.log("caso1")
        let product: any = pFichaInternacional;
        let nombreEmpresaApi = empresa.listaProductos[i].nombre
        let productoFiltrado = product.filter(i => i.referencia == nombreEmpresaApi)
        productoFiltrado = productoFiltrado[0]
        if (productoFiltrado) {
          headerSetIn = true
          this.setState({
            headerCardText: productoFiltrado.descripcion.toString(),
            headerButtonText: productoFiltrado.label.toString(),
          })
          break;
        }
      }
    }

    //case 2: case1 didnt found the data, so we setup some predefined data.
     if (!headerSetIn && pFichaInternacional.length > 0) {
       let product: any = pFichaInternacional;
       this.setState({
         headerCardText: product[0].descripcion.toString(),
         headerButtonText: product[0].label.toString()
       })
     }
  }
```

Im receiving a

```
Maximum update depth exceeded. This can happen when a component repeatedly calls setState inside componentWillUpdate or componentDidUpdate. React limits the number of nested updates to prevent infinite loops.
```

I have also tried using a setstate , instead of a local variable to set the headerSetIn  parameter. But if I do it, I think js doesnt have time to evaluate the change, and both are executed, instead of only 1

Ive tried to use () , => after the first state, but it doesnt make sense in my flow

Answer (score 0):

As far as I can understand is that you are calling setState in a for loop, which is not a good thing. Every time a certain condition is met setState is called, so you are constantly setting the state and rerendering smashing your performance and causing this.

I would suggest using a variable and get the needed data in the for loop then after you have excited the for loop simply use setState to set the state after all the data  has been looped trough.

Comment: Im using it inside a condition, so its only met once